# How to fetch updated data from temporary table to display in php?

Tags: php, database

I have got a save edit button. After I update the amount of package through all the textboxes, I select the checkbox and clicked on the save edit button the changes will be saved to the temporary table. In the next page, it will display the data and user can print out the updated data.

```html
<?php
if(!empty($_POST['pro']))
{
 if(isset($_POST['printpreview1']))
 {
  $sdate=$_POST['sdate'];
  $txt0101=$_POST['txt0101'];
  $txt0102=$_POST['txt0102'];
  $txt0103=$_POST['txt0103'];
  $txt0104=$_POST['txt0104'];
  $txt0105=$_POST['txt0105'];
  $txt0106=$_POST['txt0106'];
 }
 
 $db=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","vegetable");
 $sql1="CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tsalmast AS (SELECT pdesc,custarea,weight,packet FROM salmast WHERE sdate='".$sdate."' ORDER BY location ASC)";
 $sql2="UPDATE tsalmast SET packet='".$txt0101."' WHERE sdate='".$sdate."' AND location='0101'";
 $sql3="UPDATE tsalmast SET packet='".$txt0102."' WHERE sdate='".$sdate."' AND location='0102'";
 $sql4="UPDATE tsalmast SET packet='".$txt0103."' WHERE sdate='".$sdate."' AND location='0103'";
 $sql5="UPDATE tsalmast SET packet='".$txt0104."' WHERE sdate='".$sdate."' AND location='0104'";
 $sql6="UPDATE tsalmast SET packet='".$txt0105."' WHERE sdate='".$sdate."' AND location='0105'";
 $sql7="UPDATE tsalmast SET packet='".$txt0106."' WHERE sdate='".$sdate."' AND location='0106'"; 
 $sql8="SELECT * FROM tsalmast";
 
 $result1=mysqli_query($db,$sql1);
 $result2=mysqli_query($db,$sql2);
 $result3=mysqli_query($db,$sql3);
 $result4=mysqli_query($db,$sql4);
 $result5=mysqli_query($db,$sql5);
 $result6=mysqli_query($db,$sql6);
 $result7=mysqli_query($db,$sql7);
 $result8=mysqli_query($db,$sql8) or die("Error: ".mysqli_error($db));
 
 while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result8))
 {
  if($row['packet'] != 0)
  {
   for($i=0;$i<$row['packet'];$i++)
   {
    echo"<form action='' method='post'>";

    echo"<table style='border-collapse: collapse; text-align: left;' width='278' height='170' border='1'>";
    echo"<br><br>";
    echo"<tr>";
     echo"<th width='310' height='63' rowspan='1'>&nbsp;".$row['pdesc']."</th>";
     echo"<th width='174' rowspan='1'>&nbsp;".$row['weight']." KG</th>";
    echo"</tr>";
    echo"<tr>";
    echo"<th colspan = '2'><p>&nbsp;Name 名字：</p>";
    echo"<p>".$row['custarea']."</p></th>";
    echo"</tr>";
    echo"</table>";
    echo"<br><br><br>";
   }
  }
 }
}
else
{
 echo "None<br>";
}
?>
```

Comment: Any Error when you try  this code

Comment: @gaurav no error but it'll fetch the original data from database not the data that have been updated in temporary table

Comment: first see the output of `$sql1` query mean , it is creating temporary table or not . follow like this `$sql1="CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tsalmast AS (SELECT pdesc,custarea,weight,packet FROM salmast WHERE sdate='".$sdate."' ORDER BY location ASC)";` than `$sql8="SELECT * FROM tsalmast";`  excute these two lines, what is out of `mysqli_fetch_array`

Comment: @gaurav it will display original data from the database